# SQL Server GROUP BY NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am using SQL Server and I have to group by a few columns but only if a setting is true.

```
DECLARE @setting tinyint
SET @setting = 0

SELECT col1 FROM table1 
GROUP BY col1,
  CASE WHEN @setting = 1 THEN col2 ELSE NULL END
```

OR should I default to col1 that I always use to group by if the setting is set, so the code would would be

```
CASE WHEN @test = 1 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
```

It does actually work to use the NULL but I can't find an example on the internet to prove that it is correct usage.

Comment: fwiw, your 1st code block looks right to me, and i've used this pattern several times.

Comment: Logically, your group by could just be `GROUP BY col1,col2`, since if `@setting` is `0`, then all values that compare equal on `col1` could be returned in any order - and one of those valid orders would be as if ordered by `col2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 
GROUP BY col1,
  CASE WHEN @setting = 1 THEN col2 ELSE NULL END
```

Your usage is correct. You already know it works.
`ELSE NULL` is implied in CASE, so you could have written it as

`GROUP BY col1, CASE WHEN @setting = 1 THEN col2 END`

You could try to be coy with variants like

`GROUP BY col1, @setting * col2` *--for numeric col2*
   `GROUP BY col1, COALESCE(NULLIF(@setting,1), col2)`

But the CASE statement actually unrolls to a better, simpler plan.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @setting tinyint
SET @setting = 0

SELECT col1 FROM table1 
GROUP BY col1,
    CASE WHEN @setting = 1 THEN col2 ELSE NULL END
```

your first example should work.
For further clarification, do you want to `group by col1, col2` or `group by col1` when `@setting = 1`?

edit: Your first example is correct.

Comment: When setting = 1 then I want to group by col1, col2 and when setting =  0 I only want to group by col1.